# Запись данных в сессию

Tags: php, сессия, sql

Здравствуйте.

Скажите, безопасно ли, если я буду хранить данные в сессиях, допустим, имя, почту, ид группы?

Допустим, у меня есть несколько групп и есть личный профиль пользователя. Но у групп некоторые данные выводятся разные. Поэтому хочу сделать три шаблона профилей для разных групп, и когда пользователь авторизуется, записывать номер его группы в сессию и уже в зависимости от номера группы в сессии подключать нужный шаблон. Правильно ли так?

Comment: 1. С точки зрения кражи - относительно безопасно, сессии с сервера не уходят.
2. С точки зрения сохранности - умрут при первом же ребуте, используйте базу данных.

Comment: По поводу второго. Мне вот нужно, чтобы номер группы запоминался после входа и потом нужный шаблон подключался в зависимости от номера. Так разве не получится?

Comment: @Doj id группы можно, но необходимо предусмотреть такой сценарий:

К примеру, администрация/комьюнити сменила id/path шаблона, то в сессии у пользователей окажутся невалидные данные. Вы же не будите сбрасывать сессии у всех пользователей.

Answer (score 1):

Данные сессий в PHP по умолчанию хранятся в файлах. Их можно украсть либо получив доступ к серверу, либо украв ключ сессии у пользователя (куку). Соответственно безопасность обеспечивается надёжностью сервера и использованием HTTPS.

Но для вашей задачи хранить данные в сессии не нужно. В сессии нужно хранить только id пользователя. Когда пользователь авторизуется, вы выбираете его данные из базы (или откуда вы их выбираете) и среди этих данных должна быть и группа, к которой пользователь относится. Далее используете группу при выборе соответствующего шаблона.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю лучше сделать так чтобы при авторизации пользователя в сессию записывать его id. И потом уже по этому id вытаскивать из базы шаблон. нужно создать таблицу типа:

```
id | userName | password | shablonNumber
========================================
1  | Michael  | 1408     |       3
2  | Marta    | 1234     |       1
```

Comment: shablonNumber не лучшее имя :-), я бы рекомендовал templateId

Comment: спасиба за совет но это только для примера. В оригинале все как нужно